# $\mathbf{Cov}(x,y)$ under rotation of axes

Tags: correlation, covariance, rotation

If $\mathbf{Cov}=0$ let $u=x \cdot cos(\theta)+y \cdot sin(\theta)$

and $v =y \cdot cos(\theta)-x \cdot sin(\theta)$.

What will be $\mathbf{Cov}(u,v)$? Will it be $0$?

Comment: Is this [tag:self-study]? Please read the tag description, and if it fits, please add the tag. Otherwise ignore, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly a quick empirical example to get an intuition. Take the *x,y* as in the following figure, which have a sample covariance very close to 0 (actual value -0.038):
[image: x,y with covariance 0]

Rotate these values by 45 degrees, giving *u,v* in the following figure:
[image: u,v by rotating x,y 45 degrees]

Do you think the correlation is still 0?

---

Now to the theoretical bit. Remember that the covariance is bilinear, that is $$\operatorname{cov}(x,ay + w) = a\operatorname{cov}(x,y) + \operatorname{cov}(x,w),$$

and same for the first variable.

Using this for $\operatorname{cov}(u,v)$, and using the fact that $\operatorname{cov}(x,y) = 0$, we get $$\operatorname{cov}(u,v) = \operatorname{cov}(x,x)\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) + \operatorname{cov}(y,y)\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
$$ = [\operatorname{var}(x) +  \operatorname{var}(y)]\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

which is not necessarily 0.

Comment: In fact, the covariance of the rotated variables is $0$ only when $\theta$ is a multiple of $\pi/2$ and such rotations are negations or interchange of the original variables.

Comment: Discarding the degenerate case, when the variances are 0, that is correct!